# Query in sql -- pivot or any other way

Tags: mysql, sql

Need your help in query for the following scenario.

Table1

```
Name -ID1  - ID2 - ID3  
A1  - NULL - 11 - 12  
A2  -  14  - NULL -11
```

The above table need to translated like below

Table2

```
Name - ID  
A1  - 11  
A1  - 12  
A2 - 14  
A2 - 11
```

The table2 would be the output based on table 1. All the null values would not be considered. What is the best way to do this.

Can anyone help me with a query on how to do this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Use `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
(
    SELECT name, id1 AS id FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, id2 FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, id3 FROM table1
) t
WHERE id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: i would place the is not null WHERE statement in every select query to keep the memory table as small as possible.. UNION statement will force MySQL into using a memory table.. if the memory table becomes to large it will convert into a MyISAM disk based table.

Comment: Thank you both for your reply.

Comment: But how to approach dynamically. As the table1 can be till ID1 - ID50

Comment: "But how to approach dynamically. As the table1 can be till ID1 - ID50" @kavanabangalore why does a extra "feature/requirement" always come after somebody has given a answer I see it happen alot on stackoverflow..

Comment: Well my mistake. Chill bro

Answer (score 0):

You may use UNPIVOT:

```
SELECT name, ID 
FROM ( SELECT name, ID1, ID2, ID3 FROM table1)p
UNPIVOT
     (ID FOR ID_value IN (ID1, ID2, ID3)) AS unpvt;
```

This will eliminate the nulls automatically, and will give you the output in the pivoted format.